# FragmentPagerAdapter does not return the correct view from getItem

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, android-viewpager

First of all , I have a list of fragment

```
icons.add(new Home()));
    icons.add(new NewsFragment()));
    for (int i=0; i<gs.pages.size(); i++) { 
        SchoolPg page = gs.pages.get(i);
        if (page.page_parent_id.equals("0")) {
            icons.add(new PageFragment()); 
        }
    }
    icons.add(new InfoFragment());
```

As you can see, the first one is Home, then is News Fragment, then is a list of Page Fragment and the last one is the Info Fragment.

The problem is , in the get Item , when I change to the view pager position 1 , which should be News Fragment , but it goes to Page Fragment, why and how to fix it? Thanks

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return icons.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return icons.get(position).frag;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Update:

if I select position 2 and select position 1 , it work,
However, if I select other position than select 1 , it fail

Found out it runs two time

When I click on position 1, 
it first run the position 1 - open NewsFragment 
but at the same time run position 2 - open PageFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Fragment`s will be arranged like this:

**position 0:** `NewsFragment`

**position 1:** `PageFragment`

**.
 .
 .
 .**

**position (n-2):** `PageFragment`

**position (n-1):** `InfoFragment`

where `n = icons.size();`

Arrays like `icons` are still ordered from index 0, a relic from the days of `C`. Hope you know that!